# Make AUTO_INCREMENT reset itself on change of Parent ID

Tags: mysql, database, combinations, auto-increment

In a project assignment I have I want the one part of the `PRIMARY KEY` to reset after the other part changes value. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE shopping_center(
    centerID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
    centerName CHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT center_PK PRIMARY KEY(centerID));

CREATE TABLE staff(
    staffID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
    centerID INTEGER,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT staff_PK PRIMARY KEY(staffID, centerID));

ALTER TABLE staff
    ADD CONSTRAINT staff_FK
    FOREIGN KEY(centerID) 
    REFERENCES shopping_center(centerID);
```

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature of MySQL is not working as I intended in this situation. When I insert these values (keep in mind the `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature on the IDs, as I don't define the `centerID` or `staffID` in the `INSERT` statements):

```
INSERT INTO shopping_center (centerName) VALUES("A Shopping Center");
INSERT INTO shopping_center (centerName) VALUES("Another Shopping Center");

INSERT INTO staff (centerID, name) VALUES(1, "Staffmember 1 in centerID 1");
INSERT INTO staff (centerID, name) VALUES(1, "Staffmember 2 in centerID 1");
INSERT INTO staff (centerID, name) VALUES(2, "Staffmember 1 in centerID 2");
INSERT INTO staff (centerID, name) VALUES(2, "Staffmember 2 in centerID 2");
```

I get this result:

```
SELECT centerID, staffID, name FROM staff; 
+----------+---------+-----------------------------+
| centerID | staffID | name                        |
+----------+---------+-----------------------------+
|         1|        1| Staffmember 1 in centerID 1 |
|         1|        2| Staffmember 2 in centerID 1 |
|         2|        3| Staffmember 1 in centerID 2 |
|         2|        4| Staffmember 2 in centerID 2 |
+----------+---------+-----------------------------+
```

But what I want is for the `staffID` to reset to 1, when `centerID` changes value. This is the result I want (pay attention to the change of `staffID` values):

```
SELECT centerID, staffID, name FROM staff; 
+----------+---------+-----------------------------+
| centerID | staffID | name                        |
+----------+---------+-----------------------------+
|         1|        1| Staffmember 1 in centerID 1 |
|         1|        2| Staffmember 2 in centerID 1 |
|         2|        1| Staffmember 1 in centerID 2 |
|         2|        2| Staffmember 2 in centerID 2 |
+----------+---------+-----------------------------+
```

As the `PRIMARY KEY` as required always is unique in this case, I don't see why this shouldn't work. Is there a solution to what I want to achieve here?

Comment: That is not how auto_increment work. auto_increment only add a value to the last inserted value.

Comment: The AUTO_INCREMENT feature has done this for me before, but it seems to be random when it works and when it doesn't. I thought it maybe was setting the PRIMARY KEYs in the correct order, or maybe setting the FOREIGN KEYs in the order, but so far it all just seems random to me.

Comment: It appears you are confused about what the job of `auto_increment` is. Do you know, but **really** know, what the job of primary key is?

Comment: Isn't it to have a unique column for each row of information added to a table? So it''s not possible to achieve what I'm looking for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer your question to the point where I explain what's going on.

First off, the feature you want is available in MyISAM storage engine (kind of, there's a twist). However, transactions and referential integrity aren't available.

Now for `auto_increment` - it gives unique values to rows. However, it does this by taking **concurrency** in mind - meaning if two or more people connect and perform some work, the `auto_increment` will correctly calculate in that scenario for both people, if they are accessing the same table.

This means that `auto_increment`, for every insert, just gets incremented.  There is no relation to any record ever, which is why `auto_increment` is fast and you get a unique identifier with 100% certainty.

Another useful thing that happens is that InnoDB performs clustering based on this number. In other words, it uses this number to perform its internal data structure balancing in order to provide performance at a later stage (reading / updating of the records).

Now why is this important - if you change this number, in any way, InnoDB will re-balance its B-Tree and it will take some time to do that. It means - **never touch primary key value**.

However, all of this isn't really relevant. What's relevant is the following - *why* do you need `staffID` to change at all? Nothing bad can happen if you leave it as is.

Comment: I've realised that it's ok to just leave it as it is, but allow me to answer your question with another question: How can I prevent the staffID's AUTO_INCREMENT from resetting? As it randomly does what I ask for in the OP, I'd rather have one of the situation accur, than both.

Comment: I must admit that I don't really understand when you say that it re-sets. All `auto_increment` does is give you a higher number as you go - they don't even have to be sequential, there could be gaps between them. Is your table, by any chance, a `MyISAM` table?

Comment: By resetting, I mean that it starts at 1 again and `AUTO_INCREMENT`s. It is indeed a `MyISAM` table.

Comment: MyISAM table has this feature where it indeed does "re-set" the primary key. It does this when primary key is a compound key, and what happens is that auto_increment counter starts from 1 for every unique value of the other part of the key. Also, MyISAM table doesn't really support foreign keys - it lets you specify them but it doesn't enforce them. Long story short, if you change it to InnoDB it will work as intended.

Comment: Thank you for your time, this answer has brought alot of insight into how the MyISAM tables work!

Comment: No problem and good luck with your task. There's an alternative storage engine for MySQL called `TokuDB` - I suggest you research that one as well.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the auto_increment.

I think you should design your tables differently. What you designed now is one-to-many relationship but you need many-to-many.

So that 'Staff member 1' can be employee of both shopping centers. You should create intermediate table linking `shopping_center` and `staff`

Here is the correction to your table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE shopping_center(
centerID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
centerName CHAR(50),
CONSTRAINT center_PK PRIMARY KEY(centerID));

CREATE TABLE staff(
staffID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(50),
CONSTRAINT staff_PK PRIMARY KEY(staffID, centerID));

CREATE TABLE shopping_center2staff(
centerID INTEGER,
staffID INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT center_PK PRIMARY KEY(centerID, staffID));

ALTER TABLE shopping_center2staff
ADD CONSTRAINT staff_FK
FOREIGN KEY(staffID) 
REFERENCES staff(staffID);

ALTER TABLE shopping_center2staff
ADD CONSTRAINT center_FK
FOREIGN KEY(centerID) 
REFERENCES shopping_center(centerID);

INSERT INTO shopping_center (centerName) VALUES("A Shopping Center");
INSERT INTO shopping_center (centerName) VALUES("Another Shopping Center");

INSERT INTO staff (name) VALUES("Staffmember 1");
INSERT INTO staff (name) VALUES("Staffmember 2");

INSERT INTO `shopping_center2staff` (centerID, staffID) VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO `shopping_center2staff` (centerID, staffID) VALUES(1,2);
INSERT INTO `shopping_center2staff` (centerID, staffID) VALUES(2,1);
INSERT INTO `shopping_center2staff` (centerID, staffID) VALUES(2,2);

SELECT sc2s.centerID, sc2s.staffID, name 
FROM shopping_center2staff as sc2s
JOIN `staff` as s on sc2s.staffID = s.staffID
JOIN `shopping_center` as sc on sc2s.centerID = sc.centerID
order by sc2s.centerID;
```

The result will be

```
+----------+---------+---------------+
| centerID | staffID | name          |
+----------+---------+---------------+
|        1 |       1 | Staffmember 1 |
|        1 |       2 | Staffmember 2 |
|        2 |       1 | Staffmember 1 |
|        2 |       2 | Staffmember 2 |
+----------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: So what your suggesting is to have one table of all the staff from every single shopping center? In that case the staffID won't reset, right?

Comment: Please see my updated answer for more details. In the structure I've described there is one record for shopping center, one record for staff member but two records for relationship between center and staff member.

Comment: There was supposed to be four different persons in this example, that in this projects scenario has to be registered once for every shopping center he is employed in.

Comment: This will cause you having two records with the same primary key in the same table. It is not possible. Can you put the desired content of staff table to your question?

Comment: That is why I added centerID as a part of the PRIMARY KEY in the 'staff' table, so that the combination of staffID and centerID would be unique every time. Staffmembers cannot be registered with the same staffID in one shopping center, but two different shopping centers can have staffID = 1.